# The member with identity 'component_type_name' does not exist in the metadata collection.\r\nParameter name: identity

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, triggers

In the database I have a table called SERVICE. For this table I have triggers after INSER/UPDATE/DELETE. When I try to insert a record into the database using EF I get the error **"The member with identity 'component_type_name' does not exist in the metadata collection.\r\nParameter name: identity"**. The column 'component_type_name' does not exist in SERVICE table but in table COMPONENT_TYPES_IN_SERVICE.
This is the insert trigger for table SERVICE. When I remove the trigger from the table I dont have any problem with inserting.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateComponentTypesInServiceOnInsert]
   ON [dbo].[SERVICE] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @componentID int;
SET @componentID = 0;

DECLARE @ComponentTypeID int;
SET @ComponentTypeID = 0;

DECLARE @ComponentTypeName nvarchar(255);
SET @ComponentTypeName = null;

SELECT @componentID = component_id from inserted;

SELECT @ComponentTypeID = c.component_type_id, @ComponentTypeName = ct.description from COMPONENTS c
inner join dbo.COMPONENT_TYPES ct on c.component_type_id = ct.id
WHERE c.id = @componentID; 

Select * from COMPONENT_TYPES_IN_SERVICE cts
where cts.id = @ComponentTypeID;

IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE COMPONENT_TYPES_IN_SERVICE
        SET number_of_components = number_of_components + 1
        WHERE id = @ComponentTypeID;
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO COMPONENT_TYPES_IN_SERVICE(id, component_type_name, number_of_components)
        VALUES (@ComponentTypeID, @ComponentTypeName, 1); 
    END
END
```

Does any one knows any solution???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this:

```
Select * from COMPONENT_TYPES_IN_SERVICE cts
where cts.id = @ComponentTypeID;
```

It returns `COMPONENT_TYPES_IN_SERVICE` record back to your application and EF tries to copy returned values into `SERVICE` because it thinks that you are passing back some database generated values.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have any select statement that returns values in your trigger when using Entity Framework

Answer (score 1):

The exact cause of this unfamiliar error in most of the times is the existence of `SELECT` statements in triggers while using Entity Framework. Removing them would fix the error with a high probability.