# Entity Framework error when inserting into table with trigger - The member with identity 'AutoNumber' does not exist in the metadata collection

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, triggers

When I use Entity Framework to insert a row, I get this error:

> The member with identity 'AutoNumber' does not exist in the metadata collection.\r\nParameter name: identity

The problem is an insert trigger on the table.

Here's the table structure:

```
CustomerID | (identity, auto increment)
FirstName  |
LastName   |
```

Here's the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_Customer_INSERT] 
ON [dbo].[Customer]
FOR INSERT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT @@IDENTITY AS AutoNumber
    RETURN
```

Is it possible to use Entity Framework without deleting the trigger? Could I define 'AutoNumber' somehow? Why doesn't it just ignore the results of the trigger?

Update: I gave up and deleted the trigger.

Comment: Does that trigger work when you insert a row normally?

Comment: Yes, it's an old trigger and old db structure. I'm able to insert a row if I execute `insert into Customer values('jane','doe')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this:

```
Select * from COMPONENT_TYPES_IN_SERVICE cts
```

where cts.id = @ComponentTypeID;

It returns COMPONENT_TYPES_IN_SERVICE record back to your application and EF tries to copy returned values into SERVICE because it thinks that you are passing back some database generated values.

[The member with identity 'component_type_name' does not exist in the metadata collection.\r\nParameter name: identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238387/the-member-with-identity-component-type-name-does-not-exist-in-the-metadata-co)

Answer (score 0):

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24992192/1970301) reply

Hence, turn off validation in the EF framework:

```
context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false
```